# Controlling LED of a Logitech mouse

Tags: c#, logitech, logitech-gaming-software

My goal is to just make the mouse (G102 Lightsync) flash a color. Instead it just stays black, both IRL and in software preview, but G HUB says that it is being controlled by my executable. I've tried to set the device type

`LogitechGSDK.LogiLedSetTargetDevice(LogitechGSDK.LOGI_DEVICETYPE_ALL);`

I've tried to put a 5 second delay after `LogitechGSDK.LogiLedInit();`

I've tried to init the LED in `Main` method while flashing the mouse in a `Task` object.
Current code:

```
void StaticDecharge() // ran from Main() to eliminate static modifier
    {
        LogitechGSDK.LogiLedInitWithName("poggers"); // still gets detected as executable name.exe and not by its name in g hub
        LogitechGSDK.LogiLedSetTargetDevice(LogitechGSDK.LOGI_DEVICETYPE_ALL);
        w = Task.Run(Wait);
        w.Wait();
        LogitechGSDK.LogiLedRestoreLighting();
        LogitechGSDK.LogiLedShutdown();
    }
    
    void Wait()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        LogitechGSDK.LogiLedSaveCurrentLighting();
        LogitechGSDK.LogiLedSetLightingForTargetZone(DeviceType.Mouse, 1, 100, 50, 50);
        Console.WriteLine("pog"); // for science
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
    }
```

Comment: `w = Task.Run(Wait); w.Wait();` - there is little point to spinning up a single task that spends most of its time `Sleep`ing, only to wait for it to complete.

Comment: yes, it's just me trying to debug it, i just want to get it to work

Comment: All you have done is to introduce unnecessary complexity with no benefit.  Just call _your_ `Wait()` method directly and remove the `Task.Run`.  I don't know anything about the Logitech API but had it been say a STA COM object it could possibly explain why it doesn't work in a child thread

Comment: no, still doesn't work